# Radio button isSelected() returns false for Selenium Webdriver on Chrome browser

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify if my radio button is selected or not, but each time I am getting value as false even when I select the radio button.

HTML page

```
<div class="controls tss-radio-text-format">
   <label class="tss-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="answer_check" id="answer_check-true" value="true" checked="">
   <span class="radiobutton">
   </span><span class="tss-label">Yes</span></label><label class="tss-radio">
   <input type="radio" name="answer_check" id="answer_check-false" value="false">
   <span class="radiobutton"></span>
   <span class="tss-label">No</span></label>
</div>
```

Below is the code that I tried to click on radio button and verify if radio button Yes is selected.
The output I get is false but I was expecting true and I see Yes radio button was selected in the chrome browser I am using

```
public void clickAndVerifySelection() throws InterruptedException {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='radiobutton'])[1] ")).click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  boolean value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='radiobutton'])[1] ")).isSelected();
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isSelected()` will work only on the `input` tag
You need to take xpath like `//input[name='answer_check']`

Comment: thanks @zakaria shahed, this solution worked for me, I used  //input[id="answer_check-true"] to get the xpath  instead of //input[name='answer_check'] (as it was not unique)

Answer (score 2):

### `isSelected()`

[`isSelected()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected()) returns a *boolean* determining whether the element is selected or not. This operation only applies to `<input>` elements such as checkboxes, options in a select and radio buttons.

---

### Solution

To validate if the `<input>` associated with **Yes** is selected or not you can use either of the following strategies:

- Using *`id`* attribute:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='tss-label' and text()='Yes']//preceding-sibling::input[contains(@id, 'true')]"));
  ```
- Using *`value`* attribute:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='tss-label' and text()='Yes']//preceding-sibling::input[@value='true']"));
  ```
- Using *`checked`* attribute:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='tss-label' and text()='Yes']//preceding-sibling::input[checked]"));
  ```